# for loop reading file in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, ifstream

I am getting data from a text file by using a for loop. I am trying to get all the operation in before the for loop ends.

The text file contains:

3

add 5 5

multiply 3

divide 2

My program looks like this

```
ifstream infile("test.txt.txt");
int number; 
int first;
int second;
string command;

infile >> number;
cout<< number<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < number;i++) 
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
    infile >> command >> first >> second;
    cout << command<<"    "<<first<<"    "<<second<<endl;
}
```

And the output I get is:

3

0

add 5 5

1

multiply   3   0

2

multiply   3   0

My question is on the last iteration, why didn't it input divide 2, and not multiply 3?

Best regards,
Fre

Comment: Should  `infile >> command >> first >> second;` work when you reach the line `multiply 3`?

Comment: And to expand on @NathanOliver's comment: how does your program know if the I/O operations are working or not?

Comment: It should. I am trying to iterate over the txt file and do each command on each line.

Comment: @MichaelBurr the commands are pre-defined, the input is always be the same. I am thinking if it works for the first two lines, it should work for the third one as well.

Comment: Here's how your program interprets the input: `infile >> command >> first >> second;` "Ok, `command` = "multiply", `first` = 3, `second` = oops, "divide" is not a number, I'll put the stream in a failed state to make sure we don't do anything silly and set `second` to 0." The next loop comes along: `infile >> command >> first >> second;` "Oops, `infile` is in a failed state so I won't be reading from that".

Comment: @FreA: Unfortunately, your program thinks differently.  Think for a moment about the differences between line 2 and line 3.

Comment: @user657267 I understand now what the problem is now. Is there a way to tell it if the input isn't a correct integer to keep second = 0 and not put the stream in a failed state, because I wrote the rest of the program assuming if the second integer isn't given to assign it to 0.

Comment: @FreA Sure, just read the three values individually and `clear` the stream on error. `if (!(infile >> second)) { second = whatever; infile.clear(); }`

Comment: @user657267 
    `infile >> command; infile >> first; infile >> second;
    cout<<command<<"  "<<first<< "   "<<second<< "   "<<endl;
    if (!(infile >> second))
    {
    cout<<" not good"<<endl;
    second = 0; infile.clear(); 
    }
    prev = calc(command, first, second);`

not good is getting printed every time, even when there is an integer for the second input.

Comment: You can also enable exceptions for `infile`.